# Mercurial: How to pull and update to a specific tag

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I would like to pull the latest changesets from a remote repository and at the same time, update my local repo to a certain `tag`. Something similar as `hg fetch` or `hg pull -u`, but with an update to a tag. In two lines of code, this is:

```
hg pull
hg update mytag
```

`hg pull --help` reveals the following, but unfortunately none of them are working for a tag:

```
options:

 -u --update                update to new branch head if changesets were pulled
 -f --force                 run even when remote repository is unrelated
 -r --rev REV [+]           a remote changeset intended to be added
 -B --bookmark BOOKMARK [+] bookmark to pull
 -b --branch BRANCH [+]     a specific branch you would like to pull
 -e --ssh CMD               specify ssh command to use
  --remotecmd CMD           specify hg command to run on the remote side
  --insecure                do not verify server certificate (ignoring web.cacerts config)
```

What I tried:

```
hg pull -r mytag            only pulls the latest changesets, but no update
hg pull -u                  pulls and updates to tip, but no tag allowed
hg pull -b mytag            abort: unknown branch
hg pull -B mytag            abort: remote bookmark mytag not found
```

Is it possible to do it in one line?

Comment: Just being curious, why you want it in one line like what is the use case?

Answer (score 4):

With vanilla Mercurial, there is no command to pull & update to a certain tag, revision or whatever.

```
hg pull
hg update mytag
```

or

```
hg pull
hg update -r REVNUMBER
```

Will do the job just fine, I wouldn't complicate it with aliases and functions that saves me from doing only one extra command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with command line, this will help you.

Making a function first.

```
function pullandup(){ hg pull; hg up $1; }
```

`$1` will be replaced by the first command line argument. So this function performs `hg pull` first than takes a command line argument and `updates` the working directory to specified revision/bookmark/tag.

You can create an alias of this and call the function.

```
alias pull_up='function pullandup(){ hg pull; hg up $1; };pullandup'
```

Running

```
pull_up mytag
```

will first pull all the latest changesets and will update your working directory to `mytag`.

There may be differences while working with other terminals, this one is for BASH.